# Update Trello Card with Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

I am trying to update a Trello card with the Trello Rest API based on a specific cell changed with google apps scripts. When I update something on the google sheet, it creates another copy with the updated info of the card in Trello. The card that was supposed to update doesn’t.

The strange thing is, sometimes it works. The times when I have seen it work was when I moved that card to a different list in the same board. It also sometimes creates a copy as well.

I have posted my code for google apps scripts on the bottom of this text. Any help would be welcomed!

```js
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const boardId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const atEdit = (e) => {
  const {range: {getRow, getColumn}} = e;
  const [row, column] = [getRow(), getColumn()];

  const {getRange} = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  //Syntax for a single element is .getRange(row, column)
  const [affectedCell, getRangeCells] = [getRange(row, column).getValues(), getRange(row, 1, 1, 23)];
  const googleSheetsRowId = getRangeCells.getValues()[0][0];

  getCard(googleSheetsRowId, affectedCell);
}

const getCard = (rowId, getAffectedCell) => {
  const boardUrl = 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/' + boardId + '/cards?key=' + key + '&token=' + token;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(boardUrl);
  
  const trelloCards = JSON.parse(response);
  const {id: trelloCardId} = trelloCards[rowId];
  ui.alert(Object.keys(trelloCards[rowId]));
  updateCard(trelloCardId, getAffectedCell);
}

const buildURL = (params) => {
  var esc = encodeURIComponent;
  var query = Object.keys(params)
    .map(key => esc(key) + '=' + esc(params[key]))
    .join('&');
  return query;
}

const updateCard = (cardId, affectedData) => {
  // For now, this only works for the name but my next task is for it to work on all the values >_<
  const data = {
    'name': affectedData[0][0],
    'desc': 'sup yo',
  };
  const options = {
    'method' : 'PUT',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  const updateUrl = 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/' + cardId + '?key=' + key +'&token='+ token + '&' + buildURL(data);   

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(updateUrl, options);

  ErrHTTP(response);
}

const ErrHTTP = (response) => {
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  const responseBody = response.getContentText();

  if (responseCode === 200) {
    ui.alert('You got it!');
  } else {
    ui.alert(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the method of API you want to use?

Comment: This might be helpful as a reference on how to work with Trello's API from Google Apps Script: https://github.com/andrewroberts/TrelloApp

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-put
@Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I tested your script. But I cannot replicate your issue. When I tested it, the card can be correctly updated. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the method for replicating your issue?